# How can I adjust the placement of my html elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 for building a Web-App.
I have a ListView, which entries are not buttons.
I want to have an Icon at the left, a headline, a detail-text and a flip switch. On each entry.
I got it roughly working. But the vertical alignment of my elements could be optimized, if I knew how. That means, the icon is placed higher than the headline, but should be on the same position. As an alternative I would accept a thumbnail, but I don't know how to get that working on list entries that are not buttons.

The following is the code for the list entry template:

```
            <li id="entryTemplate" class="entry">
                <img class="ui-li-icon" />
                <h2 id="ui-li-title" class="wrap"></h2>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="flip-contain">
                    <!-- Switch -->
                </div>
                <p id="ui-li-Status" class="wrap"></p>
            </li>
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: It would be better if you add a _photo finish_ to view what do you need exactly.

Comment: Is this really jQuery mobile issue? If I were you, I would make a fiddle or SO code snippet with final render of html. From the sound of it, your problem should be solved by css

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for tagging this wrong. Of course it is not a jqm problem @mizurnix. I figured out a solution with CSS and HTML:

```
<li id="entryTemplate" class="entry">
    <img class="ui-li-icon iconfnctnlst"/>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <h2 id="ui-li-title" class="wrap"></h2>
            </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="flip-contain" class="switchfnctnlst">
            <!-- Switch -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 100%">
        <p id="ui-li-Status" class="wrap"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS, I set padding and margin dependent on the device's orientation.